# FileInfo.OpenText() Fails To Read Special Characters E.G. üò°

Tags: .net, wpf, utf-8, fileinfo, opentext

Have some text files that display many characters as � in TextBox and TextBlock.

How can I properly read and display these files in .NET WPF?

File read where fi is a FileInfo.

```
fileText = fi.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
```

In WPF I get the � character for ü ò ° and other special characters.

Have tried multiple fonts.

Culture is en-EN.

If I read the file as a Stream I get the special characters

```
System.IO.Stream fsIn = fi.OpenRead();
if (fsIn.Length == 0) return;
int curInt = -1;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((curInt = fsIn.ReadByte()) >= 0)
{
    sb.Append((char)curInt);
}
```

OpenText() appears to be reading all the special characters as byte 253

What I think I have learned is the text is not UTF8 encoded.  UTF8 uses 128-255 for control.  OpenText() is used for UTF8 encoding.   [WikiUFT8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fi.OpenText` opens a `StreamReader` with UTF8 encoding. If you need different encoding, use this instead:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fi.FullName, Encoding.Unicode))
    fileText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Of course, you don't actually need the `FileInfo` object at all, as only the path is being used by the above call.

Answer (score 1):

You've essentially answered your own question. You text file is not in Unicode format - it's probably ANSI in some specific code page. To read such files you can use a StreamReader with an encoding passed in. There are some samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5.aspx).

Comment: Thanks.  I get files to load from not unknown but uncontrolled sources.  How should I go about this?

Comment: `fi.OpenText` opens a `StreamReader` with UTF8 encoding. If you need different encoding, use this: `new StreamReader(fi.FullName, Encoding.ASCII).ReadToEnd()`. Replace `Encoding.ASCII` with the correct encoding.

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie Thanks if you had posted as an answer I would have accepted.

Comment: @Blam - I've written it up as an answer below!